Is it possible to make the Open Documents plug-in permanently active in the bottom of the window?
This is the major revision of the original question: initially, I did not know the exact reason why the Open Documents plug-in disappeared. I thought that it could happen when I exit the program and then open it, but this was not correct: the problem was not related to the exit from the program.
I will describe two situations that demonstrate the issue.
Case #1
I create an HTML file (test.html) that contains an error in the mark-up, which is supposed to activate the Syntax Checker automatically. For example:
<!DOCTYPE html><html.></html>

Then I close this test.html file.
Then I create a new text file: File > New > Text. It is titled as Untitled-1.
I go to Tools > Plug-ins > Customize Plug-ins..., select OpenDocuments, click Properties, then select Custom Bar Position: Bottom and click OK.
To activate the Open Documents plug-in, I go to Tools > Plug-ins and make the 3 Open Documents option checked.
Then the Open Documents plug-in appears in the bottom of the window.
Then I open the test.html file, switch to the Untitled-1 file, then switch back to the test.html file. The Syntax Checker activates automatically, which hides the Open Documents plug-in. This is expected. But this also deactivates the Open Documents plug-in automatically! When I look at the Tools > Plug-ins > 3 Open Documents option, I see that it has become unchecked without my permission, which should not happen: opening the Syntax Checker does not imply that the Open Documents plug-in must be deactivated. When I switch to the Untitled-1 file again, the Syntax Checker disappears automatically, but the Open Documents plug-in is not reactivated! It just disappears from the bottom of the window, which is not expected. The plug-in should be hidden, but only until the Syntax Checker is open. As soon as the Syntax Checker is closed, the plug-in is expected to reappear in its place.
Case #2
I go to Tools > Plug-ins > Customize Plug-ins..., select Explorer, click Properties, then select Custom Bar Position: Right and click OK.
To activate the Explorer plug-in, I go to Tools > Plug-ins and make the 1 Explorer option checked.
Then the Explorer plug-in appears in the right side of the window.
Now I activate the Large File Controller: either automatically (by opening a sufficiently large file) or manually (by making the View > Large File Controller element checked).
Then the Large File Controller appears in the right side of the window, which hides the Explorer plug-in. This is expected. But this also deactivates the Explorer plug-in automatically! When I look at the Tools > Plug-ins > 1 Explorer option, I see that it has become unchecked without my permission, which should not happen: opening the Large File Controller does not imply that the Explorer plug-in must be deactivated. When I close the Large File Controller, the Explorer plug-in is not reactivated! It just disappears from the left side of the window, which is not expected. The plug-in should be hidden, but only until the Large File Controller is open. As soon as the Large File Controller is closed, the plug-in is expected to reappear in its place.
So the question is: is it possible to make a plug-in reappear in the specified place as soon as the corresponding tool (the Syntax Checker or Large File Controller) is closed?

Hello, do you use the portable or desktop version of EmEditor?

@MakotoE: portable version.

Please try downloading a new copy of EmEditor portable and try again. If you still encounter problems, please contact us: https://www.emeditor.com/support/#contact

@MakotoE: Please, see the edited post. The problem is not related to a particular version (portable or desktop, old or new) of EmEditor.

Unfortunately, there is no way to have the plug-in bar reopen if another custom bar was opened on that side. I have talked to Yutaka about possibly implementing this option to reopen the plug-in, because it would be helpful.
